# Subscribe to HTTP stream using Apache NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I would like to use Apache NiFi to subscribe to a REST endpoint that continuously sends streaming data, and process this data using NiFi.

In short, the REST endpoint is provided by an external organization. I use Basic authentication to login. I do not have control over the configuration of this endpoint. I can only consume its data.

When connecting to the endpoint, the server never ends this request. Instead, the connection is kept alive. When the server processes updates to its database, a copy of this data is transmitted to the consumer via this endpoint. This allows me to replicate changes to the database.

From time to time, the server sends empty responses to keep the connection alive. I will filter these "heartbeat" responses.

How can I model this dataflow in Apache NiFi? I was thinking about using the InvokeHTTP processor, but apparently it does not support data streams. Also, how would I have to configure the processors to deal with the streaming nature of data. In other words, the processor should only once connect to the HTTP endpoint, never end this connection, and never reconnect using a pre-defined interval.

Thank you.

Comment: I never use or hear rest based streaming.  tcp sockets are more suitable for this type works.

Comment: Hello, thank you. I may agree, but again, we consume a REST api from an external organization and we cannot change how the data are delivered to us, unfortunately.

Comment: Not a standard streaming integration. You could write custom processor based on listentcp code. Or standalone application that will transform this non-standard communication to something standard to nifi.